# Scrapy Image Pipeline not downloading images

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website using scrapy to download images. When I run the code, it runs very well but it doesn't download the images even after I have specified the image pipeline nad directory in my settings.py

**spider.py**

```
import re
import scrapy
import os
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from ..items import ImagesItem


class ImageSpiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'image_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']
    # start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/']

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'http://books.toscrape.com/'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url)

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'catalogue/'), callback='parse_image', follow=True),
    )

    # save_location = os.getcwd()

    custom_settings = {
        "ITEM_PIPELINES": {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1},
        "IMAGES_STORE": '.images_download/full'
    }

    def parse_image(self, response):
        if response.xpath('//div[@class="item active"]/img').get() is not None:
            img = response.xpath('//div[@class="item active"]/img/@src').get()
            """
            Computing the Absolute path of the image file.
            "image_urls" require absolute path, not relative path
            """
            m = re.match(r"^(?:../../)(.*)$", img).group(1)
            url = "http://books.toscrape.com/"
            img_url = "".join([url, m])
            image = ImagesItem()
            image["image_urls"] = [img_url]  # "image_urls" must be a list
            yield image
```

**items.py**

```
import scrapy


class ImagesItem(scrapy.Item):
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
```

**settings.py**

```
BOT_NAME = 'images'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['images.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'images.spiders'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

ITEM_PIPELINES = {"scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline": 1}
IMAGES_STORE = "/Home/PycharmProjects/scrappy/images/images_downloader"
```

Comment: I ran your code and it worked absolutely fine, and it downloaded the images. I tried it both with settings.py and custom_settings and it worked in both of them. (I used PyCharm and scrapy 2.5.0).

Comment: I didn't run it but first you have to check if folder exists because it doesn't create it automatically - and if folder doesn't exist then it doesn't download. Second: you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables - it is called `"print debuging"`

Comment: I don't understand why you use `re.match`. And if you want to create absolute URL then it has `absolute_url = response.urljoin(relative_url)`

Comment: instead of `os.getcwd()` you can use `"."` - `"IMAGES_STORE": "."`

Comment: standard pipeline downoload to subfolder `full` - `IMAGES_STORE/full` - so you should check if you have subfolder `full`

Comment: Thank you all for your responses.
@furas I created the folder manually and yet the images did not download. I will try print debugging. For the re.match, I am following a tutorial. I will create the sub directory /full and test.

Comment: @fures I have implemented your suggestion. I created `/full` directory, changed `os.getcwd()` to '.'. You can check my spider.py edits; but still no changes. Images are still not downloading

Comment: first you could check `print( os.getcwd() )` to see in which folder it runs code - when you run it as `project` then it may run code in different folder then you expect. Next you could check what you get in console/terminal when you run it - it should display warning about problems and infromation about scraped data - I can see lines with `'images': [{'checksum': ..., path': 'full/472a819962482cb2ebdaf636d6b1b8bee4c14b7f.jpg', 'status': 'downloaded'}` which shows that it downloaded image (`'status': 'downloaded'`) in subfolder `full`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it as `project` but I tested your code as `standalone` script - and it works for me.

I put all this code in one file `script.py` and run it as `python script.py`

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class ImagesItem(scrapy.Item):
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()

class ImageSpiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'image_spider'

    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'catalogue/'), callback='parse_image', follow=True),
    )

    custom_settings = {
        "ITEM_PIPELINES": {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1},
        "IMAGES_STORE": '.', 
    }
    
    def parse_image(self, response):
        img = response.xpath('//div[@class="item active"]/img/@src').get()
        if img:
            img_url = response.urljoin(img)
            #image = dict()
            image = ImagesItem()
            image["image_urls"] = [img_url]  # "image_urls" must be a list
            yield image


# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    #'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',

    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEEDS': {'output.csv': {'format': 'csv'}},  # new in 2.1

    #'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1},  # used standard ImagePipeline (download to IMAGES_STORE/full)
    #'IMAGES_STORE': '.',                                              # this folder has to exist before downloading
})
c.crawl(ImageSpiderSpider)
c.start()
```

It creates subfolder `full` with images which have names like `0a007ac89083ad8b68c56ec0f8df5a811e76607c.jpg` because standard pipeline uses hash code as name.

It also creates file `output.csv` with rows like

```
image_urls,images
http://books.toscrape.com/media/cache/b1/0e/b10eabab1e1c811a6d47969904fd5755.jpg,"[{'url': 'http://books.toscrape.com/media/cache/b1/0e/b10eabab1e1c811a6d47969904fd5755.jpg', 'path': 'full/d78460eb2aa4417e52a8d9850934e35ef6b6117f.jpg', 'checksum': 'e7f8ece4eab2ff898a20ce53b4b50dcb', 'status': 'downloaded'}]"
```

The same information I see also directly in console

```
{'image_urls': ['http://books.toscrape.com/media/cache/ee/cf/eecfe998905e455df12064dba399c075.jpg'],
 'images': [{'checksum': '693caff3d97645e73bd28da8e5974946',
             'path': 'full/59d0249d6ae2eeb367e72b04740583bc70f81558.jpg',
             'status': 'downloaded',
             'url': 'http://books.toscrape.com/media/cache/ee/cf/eecfe998905e455df12064dba399c075.jpg'}]}
```